# I need help storing and displaying information from a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a program that allows users to choose from a list of schools to simulate a fundraiser. It then summarizes the estimated fundraising by school and by donation amount. All totals should be stored in a two-dimensional array. After processing the estimated fundraising for all schools, it should display the results in a tabular format, with each column representing a school and each row representing one of the donation amounts.

I've got most of the program down. Its now calculating the user chosen Donation amount with the selected schools population. What I would like help with is storing that information in a 2D array and then displaying it. I'm simply unsure of how I would go about doing that.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
package u2a2a1;

import javax.swing.*;

public class U2A2A1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // DeclareVariables
    String DonationChoice, SchoolChoice = "", SchoolPopulation;
    double DonationTotals[][] = new double[4][9];
    double Donation = 0;

    // Initialize the DonationTotals array to zeros
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        DonationTotals[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }

    // Create menu
    while (!SchoolChoice.equals("8")) {
      SchoolChoice =
          JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which School is Fundraising?\n"
              + "0 - Catholic Central"
              + "\n1 - Holy Cross\n2 - John Paul II\n3 - Mother Teresa"
              + "\n4 - Regina Mundi\n5 - St Joeseph\n6 - St Mary"
              + "\n7 - St Thomas Aquinas\n8 - Exit\n");

      // Ask user how much each student is donating
      DonationChoice =
          JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the donation amount?\n "
              + "0 - 25cents\n1 - 50cents\n2 - 1dollar\n3 - 2dollars");

      if (DonationChoice.equals("0")) {
        Donation = .25;
      }
      if (DonationChoice.equals("1")) {
        Donation = 0.5;
      }
      if (DonationChoice.equals("2")) {
        Donation = 1;
      }
      if (DonationChoice.equals("3")) {
        Donation = 2;
      }

      // Ask user for the polulation of the school
      SchoolPopulation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the population?");
      Integer Population = Integer.valueOf(SchoolPopulation);

      // Calculate AND Display
      System.out
          .println("================================================================================================\n");
      System.out
          .print("      CathCen  HolyC   JP II  MotherT ReginaM St.Joe  St.Tom  St.Mary  TOTAL  \n\n");

      for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
        System.out.print((row + 1) + "\t");
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
          System.out.print(DonationTotals[row][col]);

          // Print 1 tab if # is >999, 2 tabs otherwise
          if (DonationTotals[row][col] > 999) {
            System.out.print("\t");
          } else {
            System.out.print(" \t");
          }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
      }
      System.out.println("\n" + Donation * Population);
    }
  }
}
```

The following is what I would like the program to output.
For example, if the user selects "Catholic Central" a donation amount of 0.25 and a school population of 2000 I would like the program to display the calculation (250) here: (desired location indicated by "<---")

```
 _____ CathCen  HolyC   JP II  MotherT ReginaM  St.Joe  St.Tom St.Mary  TOTAL  
    0.25    0.0<--- 0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     
    0.50    0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     
    1.00    0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     
    2.00    0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: Do not start variable names with capital letters. It makes it more difficult to understand and is not recommended. The variables can be confused with classes/objects.

Comment: I was just going to say that

Comment: I had no idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the 2D array to be array[School][donations]. I believe right now its [donations][school] and I don't think it is good for your purpose.

Assuming you make the change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // for each school
    System.out.print("School name ");
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) { // print the 4
    // donation amounts in one line
        System.out.print(array[i][j]+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println(""); // move to next line and school
}
```

You need to know which school is which in the 9 arrays (`i`).

EDIT: Object approach

```
public class School {
    String name;
    int[] donations;

    public School(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        // maybe add something for donations if you want
    }

    // getters and setters for both fields
}
```

Add these objects to an `ArrayList`:

```
List<School> schools = new ArrayList<School>;
```

Loop through the list to add/change donations for each school.

This way you avoid the pains of the 2D array + array for school names.

I think this approach fits your problem much better than the array. It keeps the data tied to one school and it makes it easier to modify and add schools in the future.

Comment: Actually, the arrays size is set to [4][9] and I have set all of the values to = 0. What I'm thinking of doing is once the user chooses a school from the menu to assign that school to a certain index within the array through a series of if statements. Any idea on how I could do this?

Comment: (THIS IS MY IDEA)                        while (!SchoolChoice.equals("8")) {
      SchoolChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        "Which School is Fundraising?\n"
        + "0 - Catholic Central"
        + "\n1 - Holy Cross\n2 - John Paul II\n3 - Mother Teresa"
        + "\n4 - Regina Mundi\n5 - St Joeseph\n6 - St Mary"
        + "\n7 - St Thomas Aquinas\n8 - Exit\n");
     
      if (SchoolChoice.equals("0")) {
       //Index =
    }
      if (SchoolChoice.equals("1")) {
       //Index =
    }
      if (SchoolChoice.equals("2")) {
       //Index =
    }       ECT.................

Comment: You can do that the way you wrote but you will not have the school names stored anywhere except in the user prompt. I would try to tie the array indices  to the school names somehow but otherwise your approach should work with 9 if statements. With the amount of code I would try to think of ways to refactor the code after you write the first version.

Comment: ideas on how to assign the school names to the index' in the array?

Comment: Not sure really. Maybe another array that matches the indices with names: `String[] schools = ["school0", "school1", ...]`. It would make it easier to loop through them. Otherwise the best choice might be to make Object `School` that has the following properties: `name`, `donation1`, `donation2`, `donation3` , `donation4`. This way you forego the whole pain of arrays and just add all the `schools` to an `ArrayList` and loop through them and make changes to fields of the object. Even then you can make donations an array and put it as property of object and loop through the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for (int row = 1; row <= 4; row++) {
    System.out.print((row + 1) + "\t");
    for (int col = 1; col <= 9; col++) {
       setnumber(donations[row][col]);

       }
        System.out.println("total donation : "  Donation * Population)

  // call setFunctions
   setNumber (donations[row][col])
   DonationTotals[row][col] =donations[row][col];
```